# How are the data moving between clusters?

Tags: time-series, clustering, k-means

I am fairly new to cluster analysis and I have questions during the analysis.

I have used kmeans for my analysis.

I would like to explore how the data move through the clusters that I have calculated through time. I have the date variable available and I can aggregate my data based on these time periods that I want to explore.

what I would like to ideally explore is how data are getting closer to a cluster centroid.

Does anyone know how I can proceed?

Comment: Where is the problem? Just compute the distances to the cluster centroid...

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate cluster centroids at time 1.

Second, calculate distance of each point to the closest centroid at each time point.

Third, do whatever analysis you would like with the above results.